# Create not private object in constructor

Tags: java, swing, variables, methods, scope

I created a form with *swing* in java and i have a `Game` class like this :

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
     public Game() {
          JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
          JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
          JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    }
}
```

Now i want to create **exit event** in constructor like this:

```
 btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

But i want to create a method like this :

```
btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            exitmethod();
        }
    });
```

**exitmethod** :

```
private void exitmethod() {
     if (btnExit.getText().equals("1")){
         system.exit(0);
     }

}
```

**But i can't access `btnExit` in `exitmethod`**.

I tried to put btnExit out of constructor but it this way.app didn't work correct.

Comment: `Member variable`. Look them up and try to adapt your code. Make sure that everything is within the same class

Comment: You want to use fields, not local variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should make your `btnExit` to be the part of `Game` class scope. Something like

```
public class Game extends JFrame {
    private JButton btnExit;
    public Game() {
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        this.btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    }
}
```